# Show integral function is continuous and uniformly continuous

Tags: improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

> Let $ -\infty \le a < b \le \infty $. Function $ f:(a,b) \rightarrow R $ can be integrated in the sense of Riemann on every dense $ [c,d] \subseteq (a,b) $. The integral $ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx $ is convergent. Show that
>   $$ F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(x) dx $$
>   is continuous. Is it uniformly continuous?

We have $F(a) = 0$. From the fundamental theory of calculus $F(x)$ is continuous on $[a,x], x<b$. We have a left-side sonvergence in $b$ from definition, so $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Is it enough to prove continuity? How do I show uniform continuity?

*This is a homework assignment.*

Comment: What do you mean "left side convergence in b"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on any interval $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$ it is bounded locally.

To prove uniform continuity of $F$, the easy case is where $f$ is bounded globally on $(a,b)$ with $|f(x)| \leqslant M$ for all $a < x < b$.

The other case is where $f$ is unbounded at one or both of the endpoints.  For example, suppose $f$ is unbounded at $x = b$ and bounded and Riemann integrable on $[a,c)$ for all $c < b$.

By hypothesis, the improper integral over $(a,b)$ is convergent.  By the Cauchy criterion, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $C < b$ such that if $C \leqslant x < y < b$ we have

$$|F(y) - F(x)| = \left|\int_x^y f(t) \, dt \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

On the interval $[a,C]$, $f$ is bounded and there exists $M_C > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leqslant M_C $ for all $x \in [a,C]$.

Now see if you can complete the proof by examining the three cases (1) $x < y < C$, (2) $x < C \leqslant y$, and (3) $C < x < y$.